# How to get hierarchical number of custom taxanomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom taxonomy some thing like :

- Item - A

  - Item A-1
  - Item A-2

    - Item A-2-1
    - Item A-2-2

Now i want to get what is the number of hierarchical number of Item A-2, if we start from 0 it should be 1 and so on..

Please help me.

Comment: How about `count(get_term_children($term, $taxonomy))` ?

Comment: @vard I have tried it before, it will give 2 as it will  return number of children belongs to Item A-2. But i want the hierarchical  number.

Comment: @daniyalahmad Ah you mean the index of the item? Like Item A-1 should be 1, Item A-2 should be 2 etc? If so could you share the code that generate that hierarchical menu to see what we can do?